# Broadcast receiver stops after doing its task

Tags: android, call, recorder

I have created a small application in android which records incoming calls, its working fine, it records the call but after recording the application crashes.I get the message that Unfortunately application has stopped

here below is my code.

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    File audiofile;
    String name, phonenumber;
    String audio_format;
    public String Audio_Type;
    int audioSource;
    Context context;
    private Handler handler;
    Timer timer;
    Boolean offHook = false, ringing = false;
    Toast toast;
    Boolean isOffHook = false;
    public static boolean recordstarted = false;
    public static boolean wasRinging = false;

    private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
    private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";

    Bundle bundle;
    String state;
    String inCall, outCall;   

        @Override

            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        wasRinging = true;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "IN : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                        if (wasRinging == true) {

                            Toast.makeText(context, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/TestRecordingDasa");
                            if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                                sampleDir.mkdirs();
                            }
                            String file_name = "Rec";
                            try {
                                audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr", sampleDir);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

                            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
                            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                            recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
                            try {
                                recorder.prepare();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) { 
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            recordstarted = true;
                            recorder.start();
                            }
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                        wasRinging = false;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "REJECT || DISCO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (recordstarted) {
                            recorder.stop();
                            recordstarted = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: You should consider using Service for recording. start the Service on OFF_HOOK state and stop it in IDLE state.

Comment: Please share any error messages you get since the application is crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make your recorder as the static member(private static MediaRecorder recorder;)
2. You have to release recorder after calling recorder.stop()
   recorder.release();
3. Here is the edited code:

   ```
   package com.example.callreceiver;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.Timer;
   import java.util.logging.Handler;

   import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.media.MediaRecorder;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.Environment;
   import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    

       private static MediaRecorder recorder;
       private File audiofile;
       private String name, phonenumber;
       private String audio_format;
       private String Audio_Type;
       private int audioSource;
       private Context context;
       private Handler handler;
       private Timer timer;
       private Boolean offHook = false, ringing = false;
       private Toast toast;
       private Boolean isOffHook = false;
       private static boolean recordstarted = false;
       private static boolean wasRinging = false;

       private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
       private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";

       private Bundle bundle;
       private String state;
       private String inCall, outCall;

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Log.i("onReceive", "Receive successfully");

           if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
               Log.i("onReceive", "ACTION IN");
               if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                   Log.i("onReceive", "Bundle != NULL");
                   state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                   Log.i("onReceive", "state:"+state);
                   if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                       Log.i("onReceive", "Phone ringing");
                       inCall = bundle
                               .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                       wasRinging = true;
                       Toast.makeText(context, "IN : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                               .show();
                   } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                       Log.i("onReceive", "Phone off hook ");
                       if (wasRinging == true) {
                           Log.i("onReceive", "Phone was ringing");
                           Toast.makeText(context, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                   .show();

                           File sampleDir = new File(
                                   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                   "/TestRecordingDasa");
                           if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                               sampleDir.mkdirs();
                           }
                           String file_name = "Rec";
                           try {
                               audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr",
                                       sampleDir);
                           } catch (IOException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                           String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                   .getAbsolutePath();

                           recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                           recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
                           recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                           recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                           recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
                           try {
                               recorder.prepare();
                               Log.i("onReceive", "Prepared");
                           } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           } catch (IOException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                           recordstarted = true;
                           Log.i("onReceive", "Start recording");
                           recorder.start();
                       }
                   } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                       Log.i("onReceive", "State idle");
                       wasRinging = false;
                       Toast.makeText(context, "REJECT || DISCO",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       if (recordstarted) {
                           recorder.stop();
                           recorder.release();
                           Log.i("onReceive", "Record Stopped");
                           recordstarted = false;
                       }
                   }
               }
           } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
               Log.i("onReceive", "ACTION_OUT");
               if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                   outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                   Toast.makeText(context, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                           .show();
               }
           }


       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
it records the call but after recording the application crashes.
I get the message that Unfortunately application has stopped
```

In your code, when it gets offhook state it start recording but it blocks the on the function on "recorder.start();" and when Idle state broadcast then it crashes.

So, there are two things you can do:

-> Put your recording code start and stop both in different thread and handle accordingly.

Or

-> Make a service, put your start and stop recording code there. You can send broadcast to service when these call state Idle, offhook you get then start and stop recording accordingly.

Comment: i dont think this might be a problem for crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an instance in if else part `recorder = new MediaRecorder();` try to put this statement out side & make it globle this might solve your issue.

I have faced same issue.

The problem is you are instantiating a new MediaRecorder inside your if statement which is masking the MediaRecorder mRecorder class member. So Change:

Comment: your answer helped me but there is still some modification required.